# Split data with Tab in a table in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing an console application which writes to a text file.

I have written the code but my output doesn't give me what I need.

The output I get is as follows:

```
KCooke409155874935sa975891/1/2013
```

and it should be like this:

```
KCooke   409155874935   sa   97589   1/1/2013
```

The code I have is as follows:

```
                            foreach (var account in sortedAccounts)
                            {
                                var outputLine =
                                account.accountholder +
                                account.accountnumber +
                                account.accounttype.Substring(0, 2) +
                                account.amount +
                                account.date.ToShortDateString();

                                //output
                                File.WriteAllText(text, outputLine);
                            }
```

is it possible to split by a tab. I tried using **.Split()** but I get errors.

Thank you

Comment: I think you should override the `ToString()` method of `account.Type()` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the tab character should so what you need

```
                        foreach (var account in sortedAccounts)
                        {
                            var outputLine =
                            account.accountholder + "\t" +
                            account.accountnumber + "\t" +
                            account.accounttype.Substring(0, 2) + "\t" +
                            account.amount + "\t" +
                            account.date.ToShortDateString();

                            //output
                            File.WriteAllText(text, outputLine);
                        }
```

Comment: Thanks, Forgot about that

Answer (score 3):

You don't need splitting here, you are looking for join

```
string.Join("\t", account.accountholder,
                  account.accountnumber,
                  account.accounttype.Substring(0, 2),
                  account.amount,
                  account.date.ToShortDateString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert a Tab character `'\t'` like this:

```
var outputLine = account.accountholder + "\t" +
                 account.accountnumber + "\t" +
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach (var account in sortedAccounts)
        {
            var outputLine = string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}", 
                stringaccount.accountholder, 
                account.accountnumber, 
                account.accounttype.Substring(0, 2), 
                account.amount, 
                account.date.ToShortDateString());

            //output
            File.WriteAllText(text, outputLine);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually included a tab character in your string...

```
var outputLine =
    account.accountholder + "\t" +
    account.accountnumber + "\t" +
    account.accounttype.Substring(0, 2) + "\t" +
    account.amount + "\t" +
    account.date.ToShortDateString();
```